# how can I make this sed capture accomplish a more complex substitution

Tags: regex, linux, perl, sed, awk

when fixing mass spelling errors in my code base i have used this:

```
find . -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -name  "*min.js" -prune -o -name "*min.css" -prune -o -name "flashLocaleXml.xml" -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 egrep -n "priority=" -exec sed -i 's/replace/newval/' {} \;
```

to fix a specific spelling error in all the files in my repo.

however, i am not very good with sed captures, i want to do something like:

`X.addEventListener(LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels);`
becomes:
`EventUtil.addEventListener(X, LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels)`;

I have read up extensively but I would appreciate someone explaining how sed captures work with this as a specific example.

I have given it a few shots, but nothing I come up with works:  here are my tries

```
echo "X.addEventListener(LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels);" | sed 's/\(.*\)EventUtil\(.*EventUtil\)/\1X\2/'

echo "X.addEventListener(LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels);" | sed -r 's/(....),(....),(*\.addEventListener)(LevelUpEvent.*)/\1,\2\n\1,\2,/g' 

echo "X.addEventListener(LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels);" | sed 's/\([\.$]*\) \([\.$]*\)/\2 \1/'
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
sed 's/\([^.]*\)\([^(]*(\)/EventUtil\2\1, /'
```

Output:

```
EventUtil.addEventListener(X, LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels);
```

Explanation:

```
\([^.]*\)                  # Content until first '.'
\([^(]*(\)                 # Content until first '('
EventUtil\2\1,             # Literal 'EventUtil' plus grouped content in previous expression.
```

Answer (score 2):

This sed command will do.

```
sed 's/\(X\).\(addEventListener\)(\(LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels\));/EventUtil.\2(\1, \3);/'
```

#### Example

```
$ echo "X.addEventListener(LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels);" | sed 's/\(X\).\(addEventListener\)(\(LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels\));/EventUtil.\2(\1, \3);/'
EventUtil.addEventListener(X, LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
echo "X.addEventListener(LevelUpEvent.GENERIC_LEVEL_UP, updateLevels);" | sed -e "s/\([A-Za-z]\{1,\}\)\.addEventListener(/EventUtil.addEventListener(\1, /"
```

This regexp will recognize a variable name using

```
\([A-Za-z]\{1,\}\)
```

Then .addEventListener(

```
\.addEventListener(
```

And replace it with

```
EventUtil.addEventListener(\1
```

In which \1 represents the variable name